# Dynamics CRM SDK Context.SaveChanges permission error

Tags: c#, sdk, dynamics-crm-online

I have looked around a lot of MS Dynamics CRM blogs and SO questions and tried all the solutions but they haven't worked.

The problem I am facing is as follows: I am trying to loop through an excel file with company names and company type. I then find company with matching names in CRM and set values for some custom fields depending on the company type in excel. When I do this though code for a single company it works fine however when I try to run a loop for a large number of companies I am constantly getting:

> SecLib::CrmCheckPrivilege failed. Returned hr = -2147220943 on UserId: xxxxxx and PrivilegeType: Read.

The user in question has all privilleges and is an admin user with Read/Write CAL. Also like I pointed out I am able to do the updates for a single record. But when run as a loop that very same record throws an error.

I have been unable to find a solution for this so any help would be much appreciated. I am using MS Dynamics CRM online.

Here's my code:

```
while (!parser.EndOfData)
{
    counter++;

    if (counter >= 20) 
    {
        try
        {
            counter = 0;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception exc) 
        {
            while (exc != null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: " + exc.Message);
                exc = exc.InnerException;
            }
            continue;
        }
    }

    //Processing row
    string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

    foreach (string field in fields)
    {
        //TODO: Process field
        company.Add(fields[0]);
        category.Add(fields[1]);

        var currAccs = context.CreateQuery<Account>().Where(x => x.Name.Contains(fields[0])).ToList();
        if (currAccs != null)
        {
            foreach (var currAcc in currAccs)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Processing: " + currAcc.Name);
                currAcc.cir_MediaOwner = false;
                currAcc.cir_Agency = false;
                currAcc.cir_AdvertiserBrand = false;

                if (fields[1].Contains("MO"))
                {
                    currAcc.cir_MediaOwner = true;
                }

                if (fields[1].Contains("A"))
                {
                    currAcc.cir_Agency = true;
                }

                if (fields[1].Contains("B"))
                {
                    currAcc.cir_AdvertiserBrand = true;
                }

                try
                {
                    context.UpdateObject(currAcc);
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    while (exc != null)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: " + exc.Message);
                        exc = exc.InnerException;
                    }
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's strange, you should get that read error maybe if you're trying to update fields from a related entity where your user doesn't have access.  If you try updating the records without using the context (i.e. OrganizationService.Update(account) does the same happen? And if you try with ExecuteMultiple?

Comment: Hi Jordi and thanks for your reply. If I comment out the O rganizationService.Update(account) call I dont get any excetions but my updates also dont get committed to the CRM. So things like :        currAcc.cir_MediaOwner = true; don't work.

Comment: Meant to say to replace the context.UpdateObject(currAcc); by a service.Update(account) where account = new Account() {Id = new Guid("the id"), cir_MediaOwner = true, ... } and so on.

Comment: It looks like you're only trying to commit the changes every 20 records. I'm wondering if it is performing this using a `Bulk Update` in the background - does your user have permission to do bulk updates?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have either a Workflow or Plugin Step related to account and create/update message, impersonated with an User without the proper privileges.

For workflows, these could have the option "execute as: the owner of the workflow" ([link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeadcrmsupport/2015/10/08/dynamics-crm-workflow-execute-as-automatically-changes-to-the-owner-of-the-workflow-when-you-change-the-start-when-field/))

For plug-in steps, these have an option "Run in User's Context" that can be set to a fix user ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/register-plug-in))